# python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully on MAC M1

Tags: python-3.x, puppeteer, robotframework

I want to pip install robotframework-puppeteerlibrary on mac m1.But it have some error.
after install I try to solve by `pip install --upgrade pip pip install --use-pep517 greenlet`  the result is the same before. And then I `brew install greenlet`  again. It doesn't working.I don't how to solve this problem.
Expected result : I want to use puppeteer on mac with robotframework.

```
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from importlib-metadata>=1.4->pyppeteer==1.0.2->robotframework-puppeteerlibrary) (3.12.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: greenlet
  Building wheel for greenlet (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [243 lines of output]
```

```
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
      1 warning and 20 errors generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for greenlet
  Running setup.py clean for greenlet
Failed to build greenlet
Installing collected packages: pyee, greenlet, playwright, robotframework-puppeteerlibrary
  Attempting uninstall: pyee
    Found existing installation: pyee 9.0.4
    Uninstalling pyee-9.0.4:
      Successfully uninstalled pyee-9.0.4
  Attempting uninstall: greenlet
    Found existing installation: greenlet 2.0.2
    Uninstalling greenlet-2.0.2:
      Successfully uninstalled greenlet-2.0.2
  Running setup.py install for greenlet ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for greenlet did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [245 lines of output]
      running install
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/greenlet
      copying src/greenlet/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/greenlet
```

```
 fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
      1 warning and 20 errors generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Rolling back uninstall of greenlet
  Moving to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11/greenlet/
   from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11/~reenlet
  Moving to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/greenlet-2.0.2.dist-info/
   from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/~reenlet-2.0.2.dist-info
  Moving to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/greenlet/
   from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/~reenlet
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> greenlet

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I want to pip install package and use with robotframework.